# Two DIV's next to each other. 1st text, 2nd image. Image variable width. Text fill remaining space in 1st DIV?

Tags: css, image, html, css-float

The following is within a container that is 960px wide.

I want to have two divs (title, text) on the left of the page, with an image on the right that has a variable width. I want the contents of the divs on the left to fill the remaining space the image isn't using without wrapping round it.

[image]

Any help you can give to do this is most appreciated.

Thanks,
Andy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the image first in your HTML. Float it to the right.

"without wrapping round it." isn't clear. You mean to scale the text so that it fits in the vertical space the image's height provides? Or you don't want to allow the text underneath the image to take up the whole window width (i.e. give the text a right padding the size of the image width)?

Comment: Putting the image first in the html has worked. I meant for the text not to wrap underneath the image. Thank you.

Comment: Hi. I have only just tested the fix with text that extends below the image and it is wrapping. How would you tackle the right padding on the text, given the image width is variable?

Comment: For prosperity, I fixed the wrap with [overflow: hidden] on the text.

Comment: Did you solve it? I mean, does `overflow:hidden` work on the text? Aren't you hiding information that way?

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to find the layout that you're looking for at ['Layout Gala'](http://blog.html.it/layoutgala/), a site which has a collection of 40 pre-defined web page layouts done in CSS. All pages use the same HTML markup, and only are changed via CSS.

Good luck, and hope this helps.